# Why is the RCA church more literal in scripture where the UCC church is allegorical?

Tags: symbolism, denomination, biblical-theology

I’ve attended numerous churches in both RCA and UCC denominations in which RCA had a very literal take on the crucifixion and resurrection where the UCC church has a very allegorical approach.  Excluding talking about this specific instance I’m asking about why there is a difference in how it was taught.

** Why is the RCA church more literal in scripture where the UCC church is allegorical?**

I’ve noticed during switching denominations specifically RCA reformed church of America and UCC united church of Christ, RCA seems to have a more literal translation of scriptures to which is applied to daily life.  UCC on the other hand has taken a more allegorical and symbolic approach.

*I edited the question to exclude asking about specific events in the Bible and focused it more on the observed differences in how Christianity is taught*

Comment: We consider groups Christian for the purposes of this website if they call themselves Christian. With that in mind, there are Christian groups who consider none of the Bible allegorical or symbolical, groups who consider the entire thing symbolical, and almost everything in between. We don't look for what people might consider "the truth" on this site (which is a secular website); we look for what is taught by the various Christian denominations.

Comment: I will edit the question to be more specific in terms of differences in between denominations.

Comment: *Much* more answerable - and more interesting!